# Is there any reason to turn on clrf handling for a windows-only shop?

Tags: git

In a windows-only shop, is there any reason to have `core.autocrlf` set to anything other than `false`?

My thought is that I don't want my DCVS modifying my files.

But the default always seems to be to turn on autocrlf.

Should I re-consider turning that on?

Comment: So, to be sure, you mean you want the repo objects themselves to have CR-LF termination, like the working copies.

Comment: Are your servers Windows too?

Comment: I mean that I don't want the repo ever changing my files, whether they be CR-LF or not.   If it's CR-LF in the working directory, don't change it.  If it's LF only in the working directory, don't change it.

We are using a BitBucket server, which runs on linux.

Comment: If you have it enabled from the start, it won't do harm. But if you added some files before turning it on, git will begin seeing them as modified, although they're not